# Java class does not correctly generate RGB or sepia images

Tags: java, arraylist, rgb

I am making a class in Java that receives a BMP image, from which I must generate three images each for its RGB tone, that is, a copy of the image only with the red tone, another only with the green tone and another only with the blue hue, for this I can only use ArrayList or normal Arrays, that is, I cannot use classes like BufferedImage.

The images are generated for me but they appear corrupted and cannot be opened, when I open them it appears that the format of the generated image is incompatible. The code is the following:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BmpHandlerCore {  // this is the original class
    public static void separateRGB(String fileName) { // this is the method that I created 
        try {
           FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
           byte[] header = new byte[54];
           fileInputStream.read(header);
           int width = byteArrayToInt(header, 18);
           int height = byteArrayToInt(header, 22);
           int imageSize = byteArrayToInt(header, 34); // this is the size of the image in bytes (the size of the image is the size of the header + the size of the image data)
           byte[] imageData = new byte[imageSize]; // this is the array that will hold the image data (the size of the array is the size of the image in bytes)
           fileInputStream.read(imageData); // this is the method that will read the image data into the array imageData
           ArrayList<Byte> redChannel = new ArrayList<>(); // this is the array that will hold the red channel  (the size of the array is the size of the image in bytes)
           ArrayList<Byte> greenChannel = new ArrayList<>(); // this is the array that will hold the green channel  (the size of the array is the size of the image in bytes) 
           ArrayList<Byte> blueChannel = new ArrayList<>(); // this is the array that will hold the blue channel  (the size of the array is the size of the image in bytes)
           for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i += 3) { // this is the loop that will iterate through the image data array and separate the RGB channels into their respective arrays (redChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel)
           blueChannel.add(imageData[i]); // this is the statement that will add the blue channel data to the blueChannel array (the blue channel data is the first byte of every pixel) 
           greenChannel.add(imageData[i + 1]); // this is the statement that will add the green channel data to the greenChannel array (the green channel data is the second byte of every pixel) 
           redChannel.add(imageData[i + 2]); // this is the statement that will add the red channel data to the redChannel array (the red channel data is the third byte of every pixel)
         }
        saveImage(redChannel, width, height, "Image-red.bmp"); // this is the statement that will save the red channel data to a new file called "Image-red.bmp" 
        saveImage(greenChannel, width, height, "Image-green.bmp"); // this is the statement that will save the green channel data to a new file called "Image-green.bmp" 
        saveImage(blueChannel, width, height, "Image-blue.bmp"); // this is the statement that will save the blue channel data to a new file called "Image-blue.bmp" 
        fileInputStream.close(); // this is the statement that will close the fileInputStream 
    } catch (IOException e) { // this is the catch statement that will catch any IOExceptions that may occur 
        e.printStackTrace(); // this is the statement that will print the stack trace of the IOException 
    }
}  
  public static void generateSepiaTone(String fileName) { // this is the method that will generate the sepia tone effect 
     try { 
      FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName); // this is the statement that will create a new FileInputStream object called fileInputStream 
        byte[] header = new byte[54]; // this is the array that will hold the header data (the size of the array is 54 bytes) 
        fileInputStream.read(header); // this is the statement that will read the header data into the header array   
        int width = byteArrayToInt(header, 18); // this is the statement that will convert the width data from the header array into an integer and store it in the variable width 
        int height = byteArrayToInt(header, 22); // this is the statement that will convert the height data from the header array into an integer and store it in the variable height 
        int imageSize = byteArrayToInt(header, 34); // this is the statement that will convert the image size data from the header array into an integer and store it in the variable imageSize 
        byte[] imageData = new byte[imageSize]; // this is the array that will hold the image data (the size of the array is the size of the image in bytes) 
        fileInputStream.read(imageData); // this is the statement that will read the image data into the imageData array 
        ArrayList<Byte> sepiaTone = new ArrayList<>(); // this is the array that will hold the sepia tone data (the size of the array is the size of the image in bytes) 
        for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i += 3) { // this is the loop that will iterate through the image data array and apply the sepia tone effect to each pixel 
           int blue = imageData[i] & 0xFF; // this is the statement that will convert the blue channel data from the imageData array into an integer and store it in the variable blue 
           int green = imageData[i + 1] & 0xFF; // this is the statement that will convert the green channel data from the imageData array into an integer and store it in the variable green 
           int red = imageData[i + 2] & 0xFF; // this is the statement that will convert the red channel data from the imageData array into an integer and store it in the variable red 
           int sepiaBlue = (int) (0.272 * red + 0.534 * green + 0.131 * blue); // this is the statement that will calculate the sepia blue channel data and store it in the variable sepiaBlue 
           int sepiaGreen = (int) (0.349 * red + 0.686 * green + 0.168 * blue); // this is the statement that will calculate the sepia green channel data and store it in the variable sepiaGreen 
           int sepiaRed = (int) (0.393 * red + 0.769 * green + 0.189 * blue); // this is the statement that will calculate the sepia red channel data and store it in the variable sepiaRed 
          sepiaTone.add((byte) sepiaBlue); // this is the statement that will add the sepia blue channel data to the sepiaTone array (the sepia blue channel data is the first byte of every pixel) 
          sepiaTone.add((byte) sepiaGreen); // this is the statement that will add the sepia green channel data to the sepiaTone array (the sepia green channel data is the second byte of every pixel) 
          sepiaTone.add((byte) sepiaRed); // this is the statement that will add the sepia red channel data to the sepiaTone array (the sepia red channel data is the third byte of every pixel)
         } 
        saveImage(sepiaTone, width, height, "Image-sepia.bmp"); // this is the statement that will save the sepia tone data to a new file called "Image-sepia.bmp" 
        fileInputStream.close(); // this is the statement that will close the fileInputStream 
     } catch (IOException e) { // this is the catch statement that will catch any IOExceptions that may occur 
        e.printStackTrace(); // this is the statement that will print the stack trace of the IOException 
     } 
   } 
   public static void saveImage(ArrayList<Byte> imageData, int width, int height, String fileName) { // this is the method that will save the image data to a new file 
    try { 
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName); // this is the statement that will create a new FileOutputStream object called fileOutputStream 
    byte[] header = createBmpHeader(width, height, imageData.size()); // this is the statement that will create a new header array and store it in the variable header 
    fileOutputStream.write(header); // this is the statement that will write the header data to the fileOutputStream 
    for (int i = 0; i < imageData.size(); i++) { // this is the loop that will iterate through the imageData array and write the image data to the fileOutputStream 
      fileOutputStream.write(imageData.get(i)); // this is the statement that will write the image data to the fileOutputStream 
       } 
       fileOutputStream.close(); // this is the statement that will close the fileOutputStream 
     } catch (IOException e) { // this is the catch statement that will catch any IOExceptions that may occur 
         e.printStackTrace(); // this is the statement that will print the stack trace of the IOException 
      } 
   } 

   private static byte[] createBmpHeader(int width, int height, int imageSize) { // this is the method that will create a new header array 
        byte[] header = new byte[54]; // this is the array that will hold the header data (the size of the array is 54 bytes) 
        header[0] = 0x42; // this is the statement that will set the first byte of the header array to 0x42 
        header[1] = 0x4D; // this is the statement that will set the second byte of the header array to 0x4D 
        header[2] = (byte) (imageSize + 54); // this is the statement that will set the third byte of the header array to the size of the image in bytes plus 54 
        header[10] = 0x36; // this is the statement that will set the eleventh byte of the header array to 0x36 
        header[14] = 0x28; // this is the statement that will set the fifteenth byte of the header array to 0x28 
        header[18] = (byte) width; // this is the statement that will set the nineteenth byte of the header array to the width of the image 
        header[19] = (byte) (width >> 8); // this is the statement that will set the twentieth byte of the header array to the width of the image shifted right by 8 bits 
        header[20] = (byte) (width >> 16); // this is the statement that will set the twenty-first byte of the header array to the width of the image shifted right by 16 bits 
        header[22] = (byte) height; // this is the statement that will set the twenty-third byte of the header array to the height of the image 
        header[23] = (byte) (height >> 8); // this is the statement that will set the twenty-fourth byte of the header array to the height of the image shifted right by 8 bits 
        header[24] = (byte) (height >> 16); // this is the statement that will set the twenty-fifth byte of the header array to the height of the image shifted right by 16 bits 
        header[34] = (byte) imageSize; // this is the statement that will set the thirty-fifth byte of the header array to the size of the image in bytes 
        header[35] = (byte) (imageSize >> 8); // this is the statement that will set the thirty-sixth byte of the header array to the size of the image in bytes shifted right by 8 bits 
        header[36] = (byte) (imageSize >> 16); // this is the statement that will set the thirty-seventh byte of the header array to the size of the image in bytes shifted right by 16 bits 
        header[37] = (byte) (imageSize >> 24); // this is the statement that will set the thirty-eighth byte of the header array to the size of the image in bytes shifted right by 24 bits 
        return header; // this is the statement that will return the header array 
        }  
    private static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] byteArray, int index) { // this is the method that will convert a byte array to an integer 
        return byteArray[index] & 0xFF | (byteArray[index + 1] & 0xFF) << 8 | (byteArray[index + 2] & 0xFF) << 16 | (byteArray[index + 3] & 0xFF) << 24; // this is the statement that will convert a byte array to an integer and return it 
      }
  }
```

Comment: I’d first test opening the images, maybe in an image editor or using ImageIO.read - this will let you know if the images are corrupted or your code is wrong

Comment: I'd also consdier having a look at something like [this example](https://github.com/nayuki/BMP-IO/blob/master/src/io/nayuki/bmpio/BmpReader.java) to compare the reading of the BMP data

Comment: Other people will find your code much more readable if you remove “this is the statement that will” from every comment that contains it.  And remove “this is the” from all other comments.